# How to consolidate Health Check Script Output of different servers

Tags: shell, unix, solaris

I have develop a shell script which we used for health check of servers and then send it on email after every 8 hours.

Its working fine on 8 servers, now requirements are that how i can consolidate output of these eight servers?

Any recommendations?

like ftp all output in one folder and then send that files as attachments or any other approach?

Regards,

Comment: What do you want to do with the data?  Why are you emailing it?  Do you need all of it, or are there just a few interesting bits?

Answer (score 0):

1. Split health-check and emailing into 2 different scripts.
2. Run emailing on one of servers (after health-checks are complete on all servers)

To consolidate:

- Easiest way would be to establish shared/**NFS mount** across all servers
- Alternatively - configure ssh keys to passwordlessly grab output-files from other servers via **scp**